# round up a value if over .5 and do nothing if under .5

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to round values up if they are over .5 and do nothing if they are under .5 for example

- 3.4 => 3.4
- 3.6 => 4
- 24.8 => 25
- 23.3 => 23.3
- 25.55 => 26
- 25.5 => 25.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.5,ROUND(A1,0),A1)
```

where the value to check is in A1. Or if you don't mind it being a little less clear what's going on:

```
=MAX(CEILING(A1-0.5,1),A1)
```

Comment: You sir are a legend

Comment: Very kind. The interaction with @NiteshHalai, put me in "Code-Golf" mode, so then I wanted to find a "shorter" answer ... which I've just added, though I think the original answer is easier to read so in case others might need to make sense of what's going on in the spreadsheet, I'd stick with the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.5,ROUNDUP(A1,0),A1)
```

Comment: If this were code-golf, I'd win by 2 bytes. Though I think you were ahead by 5 seconds, so ...

Comment: @SteveLovell I am sure you were ahead by the same amount of time. Sort by oldest, you will come on the top  :)

Comment: Oh yeah ... perhaps the time stamps aren't accurate when they show in seconds (or I might have got confused reading them).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,1)>0.5,ROUND(A1,0),A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while marking student assignments. I searched and found `MROUND` which does this:

- `MROUND(1.5,1)` = 2
- `MROUND(1.4,1)` = 1
- `MROUND(1.6,1)` = 2

However, it just rounds up OR down, without preserving the decimal. I added it here because this answer cropped up when searching for a solution.

See [Office Support: MROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MROUND-function-C299C3B0-15A5-426D-AA4B-D2D5B3BAF427) or (with examples) [ExcelFunctions.net](https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-mround-function.html)